# Converting BGR image to grayscale using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, colors

I have a small question hope you guys can help me. I know that to convert a RGB image to grayscale without using numpy, we can use:

```
img = cv2.imread(input_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
r, g, b = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
img_gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
```

Now I want to read the image by BGR scale then convert that BGR image to grayscale not using `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, how can I do it with the similar code above?

Comment: I don't understand. You are already not using `COLOR_BGR2RGB` ?

Comment: Edited. Apologize for wrong typing.

Comment: I still don't understand. Your code doesn't use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` either - you have already achieved your stated goal, surely?

Comment: I thought the code above is to read and convert a RGB image to Gray scale. Actually I want to know the same way for BGR to Gray scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV will read the file into memory in BGR order, even though it is RGB on disk. That's just the way it works. So you need to change your second line to:

```
b, g, r = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
```

Then your third line will work correctly, although you may want to make unsigned 8-bit integers with:

```
img_gray = (0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b).astype(np.uint8)
```

By the way, you could actually do it faster with `numpy` like this:

```
import numpy as np

grey = np.dot(img[...,::-1], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]).astype(np.uint8)
```